# Namespace configuration when set a specific context-root in Struts 2

Tags: configuration, struts2, action-mapping, struts2-namespace

When I set a `context-root` in `weblogic.xml` for my application, what is the default namespace for package in Struts 2?

ex:
I set

```xml
<context-root>/home/app/exec</context-root>
```

and I access my app with the following URI:

`localhost:8081/home/app/exec/index.html`

insted of

`localhost:8081/NameOfMyApp/index.html`

In the other hand I Know that in Struts2 action namespace map to folder structure.
Example on the following link: [Struts 2 Namespace configuration example and explanation](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/).

What is the correct namespace for the situation in case that `ServletContext` is not the name of my app but is the `context-root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace is the part that is calculated after the context path and before the action name. On the other hand a namespace is an attribute of the package that holds the actions belonging that namespace. A default action mapper is using both attributes to find the action config corresponding the namespace and action name.

For detailed explanation of default action mapper you can read javadocs [DefaultActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/DefaultActionMapper.html).

You can read more about [action configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html) and [ActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) on the Struts docs site.

You should also know that the action mapper returns [ActionMapping](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapping.html). However, to execute an action requires [ActionConfig](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/ActionConfig.html) which is determined by the Struts using run-time configuration.