# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, collections

I have UniversalComparator and it does all the task related to sorting, It uses reflection API to recognized the method name and invocatio target.

Now what happened is, I need to sort the `sites`, previously it was sorted using `"name"`, now what happened is, user need to upload documents in frequency of monthly, quarterly,semi and annually.

**REQUIREMENT**

If document not uploaded in any of the frequency, that data represent with `white` color, rest of the blocks are reprsented as `red` color.

There are six SITES right now, 
first site has only one white block
second site has no white block.
third site has no white block
four has three white block
fifth has three white block
sixth has three white block

so the count is 
1
0
0
3
3

Now whta I did, I cretaed an ArrayList of Integer and store all the count
now I need to sort the list of SITE Block on behalf of this count so it should be like

0
0
1
3
3

**CODE**

```
package com.lear.common.utility;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Comparator;



public class UniversalComparator implements Comparator {

    /**
     * static final int ASCENDING
     */
    public static final int ASCENDING = 1;

    /**
     * static final int DESCENDING
     */
    public static final int DESCENDING = -1;

    /*
     * int for descAscIndicator
     */
    private int descAscIndicator = 1;

    /*
     * String to store method Name
     */
    private String methodName = "toString";

    /**
     * Constructor for UniversalComparator
     * 
     * @param descAscIndicator
     *            int to store descAscIndicator.
     */
    public UniversalComparator(int descAscIndicator) {
        this.descAscIndicator = descAscIndicator;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for UniversalComparator
     * 
     * @param methodName
     *            : name of method as criteria
     * @param descAscIndicator
     *            : order of sorting
     */
    public UniversalComparator(String methodName, int descAscIndicator) {
        this(descAscIndicator);
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    /**
     * This Method compare Two Objects
     * 
     * @param o1
     *            : An Instance of Object.
     * @param o2
     *            : An Instance of Object.
     * @return int
     */
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Object comp1 = null;
        Object comp2 = null;

        try {
            Method o1_Method = (o1.getClass()).getMethod(methodName, null);
            Method o2_Method = (o2.getClass()).getMethod(methodName, null);
            comp1 = o1_Method.invoke(o1, null);
            comp2 = o2_Method.invoke(o2, null);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Method does not exist" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal access" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("InvocationTargetException"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        Comparable c1 = (Comparable) comp1;
        Comparable c2 = (Comparable) comp2;
        return c1.compareTo(c2) * descAscIndicator;
    }

    /**
     * Check for Equality obect
     * 
     * @param obj
     *            : An Instance of Object.
     * @return boolean return true if equal or false if not
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

ScoreCardManager.java

```
List<Integer> naSiteDataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public String getComparativeSiteAnalysis(Integer divId, String lang, int selectedYear) {

// PLENTY OF CODE HERE
    int annualDataCount = site.getComparativeColorAnnual().equalsIgnoreCase("White") ? 1 : 0;
                naSiteDataCount = monthlyDataCount + quaterlyDataCount + semiAnnualDataCount + annualDataCount;
                naSiteDataList.add(naSiteDataCount);
                naSiteCounter.add(naSiteDataCount);
                site.setNaSiteCount(naSiteDataList);
                site.setNaSiteCounter(naSiteCounter);
                System.out.println("datacount is" + naSiteDataCount);
            }
          // THIS LINE
            Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("getNaSiteCount", 1));
```

**Site.java**

```
 public class Site{

// lot of properties

    private List<Integer> naSiteCount;

    public List<Integer> getNaSiteCount() {
            return naSiteCount;
        }

        public void setNaSiteCount(List<Integer> naSiteCount) {
            this.naSiteCount = naSiteCount;
        }
```

}

Comment: apparently it is using the `getNaSiteCount` method expecting to get an `Comparable`, which probably is not being returned. It is more like it is returning an `ArrayList` (despite the misleading method name). I can't see that method in posted code, so it is all just a guess...

Comment: See My edits Carlos

Comment: as I suspected... the method is returning an `ArrayList` which is not an instance of `Comparable`. The code is trying to sort `sites` using the list to determine the order, but not sorting the list itself (maybe `...sort(getNaSiteCount)` but not sure if I understood the requirement)

Comment: You are correct Carlos, so what should I do to achieve the sorting on behalf of counts, I need a list to store the counts

Comment: you should try with sites.sort(new UniversalComparator("getNaSiteCount", 1))

Comment: what do you want to sort, the count list or `sites`? if it is the list, the answer is already in my last comment! If it si `sites`, you must first specify how it should be sorted (sum of counts, max count, min count, ...)!

Comment: I want to sort SITES on behalf of the list of  counts carlos –

Comment: The whole idea of a "universal" comparator seems pretty wacky to me - even more so when you try to bring reflection into the mix. Why can't you just define specific comparators, e.g. `Comparator.comparing(Object::toString)`? Make it descending using `.reversed()`?

Comment: Andy I am working on legacy project which is developed on java 7

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is a really awful approach to this. You have absolutely no type safety in this code. You have no guarantee that a method with the name you supply as a string actually exists. You have no guarantee that it takes no arguments. You have no idea what exceptions it might throw.

If you were working in Java 8 plus, it would be trivial to implement specific comparators:

```
Comparator<Object> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Object::toString);
```

but the lack of Java 8 features isn't a reason to do it with reflection.

Define an abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractComparator<T, C extends Comparable<? super C>> implements Comparator<T> {
  abstract C toComparable(T object);

  @Override public int compare(T a, T b) {
    return toComparable(a).compareTo(toComparable(b));
  }

  Comparator<T> reverse() {
    return new Comparator<T>() {
      @Override public int compare(T a, T b) {
        return toComparable(b).compareTo(toComparable(a));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then implement this for your specific cases:

```
Comparator<Object> comparator = new AbstractComparator<Object, String> {
  @Override String toComparable(Object object) { return object.toString(); }
}.reverse();
```

If you are using Guava or some other library with a `Function`-like class, or are happy to define it yourself, you can of course take a compositional approach, rather than using inheritance:

```
Comparator<Object> comparator = new ConcreteComparator<>(new Function<Object, String>() {
  @Override public String apply(Object object) {
    return object.toString();
  }
});
```

Provided you don't use raw types around either the comparator or the things you are comparing, `ClassCastException`s will now be impossible.